# Terran bio versus Protoss

Tags: starcraft-2

Terran bio army consisting of:

- Marines
- Marauders
- Ghosts
- Medivacs
- Vikings

What is the focus kill priority for the Terran versus a Protoss, assuming the Protoss has the following:

- Zealots
- Stalkers
- Sentries
- Colossi
- High Templars

**Which Terran unit should focus on what Protoss unit? And what would be the best unit position for the Terran player?** Let's assume an open ground engagement for this last question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marines counter Zealots if you have Medivacs + Stim Pack.
Marauders should be focusing on Stalkers first but they can also fire at Zealots.

Ghosts counter High Templars with EMPs.
Medivacs should be slightly in the back curing marines.
Vikings counter Colossi (also Siege Tanks).

Sentries are best countered by Hellions, Banshees or Siege Tanks, but they are a relatively weak unit so you can kill them anytime but better as soon as possible (especially for those force fields that split your army = death).

I'd keep marauders in the front and marines slightly in the back with medivacs curing them. Bring Vikings to the front, snipe the colossus and bring them back immediately. Stalkers will snipe down your Vikings if you don't make sure they're only there sniping and brought back. Also don't position Vikings directly above Stalkers. They will die like flies. You can transform them to ground units for additional firepower later (it never harms).

While they're busy sniping the colossi, get the ghosts (possibly cloaked) and emp the Protoss army but aiming at the high templars. High templars without shields = dead. If the High Templars are clumped together, EMP is better than sniping, since you hit all of them at once, but if you see one at a time, then sniping might be a better choice. EMPing doesn't just lower shields but also reduces energy for spellcaster units. So you should keep this in mind when deciding between Snipe vs EMP.

This is what I would do. It's task-intensive so it might help to use unit groups.

Comment: I still think you should snipe the high templars it will one shot them and it is better to get rid of them asap. If they can get a few storms off the colossus will eat through your army in a matter of milliseconds.

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma I've added something more about that part in my answer. See the edit. :)

Comment: although I still dont agree with you, the answer makes more sense now. Thanks for improving.

Answer (score 1):

Snipe them templars! then get your marauders in the front line to absorb most of the colossus damage. Target the colossus first assuming the high templar are already gone. As for your medivacs, it sort of depends on how many stalkers he has. If he has way more stalkers then zealots bring your marines in first and let the medivacs heal from behind. If he only has a few stalker bring your medivacs in with the marauders to absorb some shots. Try to get as much spread on your units as possible to get the most shots off and to take significantly less damage from storms and colossus. Hope this helps. Cheers, Marco